# How to avoid repetition of "something" and "some stuff"?

Tags: phrase-requests, word-usage

Is there any other word which can be used instead of **something** and **some stuff**, and how can the use of **something** and **some stuff** be avoided.

For example:

> He saw her dwelling on something; it seemed more like she was trying to recall something.

can it be written differently, without using **something** and/or **some stuff**?

Comment: This looks like Off Topic writing advice to me.

Comment: There's a correction / re-evaluation rather than an elaboration here, and, before the style is addressed, the overall structure needs amending:  He saw her dwelling on something – no; it seemed more like she was trying to recall something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are any number of possible alternatives to repeating the word *something*. Style sometimes requires trial and error. First, before the trial, determine what mood you are trying to capture. Then conjure up some words, some apt words, to evoke that mood. Alternatively, determine the shades of meaning you are after, and what it is you want to say. Are you trying to be factual, matter of fact, casual, specific, observational, persuasive, inspiring, or informative? Or are you striving for a combination of meanings?

The following list could go on and on. I suggest you are limited only by your imagination, your powers of invention, and your purpose in crafting the sentence.

> - When he saw her initially, he thought she was lost in thought. With a second look, however, she seemed to be straining for a lost memory.
> - Initially he perceived her as simply meditating, but then he realized she was actually trying to recall a lost memory.
> - What he initially thought to be quiet meditation turned out for her to be a stroll down memory lane.
> - Upon seeing her initially, he thought she was meditating; after looking more closely, he saw she was searching for a lost memory.
> - Initially, he thought her pensive pose suggested mediation; then he realized she was reminiscing.
> - To him, she appeared at first to be lost in thought; as it turned out, she was simply nostalgic.
> - Upon seeing her, he thought at first she was deep in thought, but then he realized she was straining to recall something.
> - At first, he detected a pensive expression, but then he realized she was trying hard to retrieve a memory.

Answer (score 1):

I run across this same problem, and I have found that to avoid monotonous wording, a complete change in the wording is necessary.

For example:

> He saw her dwelling on something.
>   He saw that her attention was fixed/fixated.
>   He saw that she was focused.

And

> It seemed like she was trying to recall something.
>   She seemed retrospective.

My point is that there aren't many substitute words. It becomes more an exercise in creative writing. But advice on that is off-topic here.